# Android OurOfMemoryError: Bitmap exceed VM budget during Bitmap.createBitmap

Tags: android, image-processing, out-of-memory

I am trying to make a photo processing app in Android.
when I try to read the photo from src file, it returned OutOfMemoryError

I tried to use

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(src.width, src.height, src.getConfig());
```

and the input photo is just a normal picture with 29KB
that's totally weird
I also tried this

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

but results are the same, could anyone tell me what's wrong with this???
I totally out of idea...

Some part of my code used

```
ImageView image, processedImage;
Bitmap bitmapImage;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.testingImage);
    processedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prcoessedImage);

    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.testingimage);

    bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    imageProcessing(bitmapImage);
}

public static Bitmap imageProcessing(Bitmap src) {
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
    ...
}
```

logcat

```
08-31 15:50:54.694: D/ddm-heap(5497): Got feature list request
08-31 15:50:54.842: D/dalvikvm(5497): Trying to load lib lib_glossary.so 0x0
08-31 15:50:54.842: I/dalvikvm(5497): Unable to dlopen(lib_glossary.so): Cannot load library: load_library[1051]: Library 'lib_glossary.so' not found
08-31 15:50:54.842: E/MBGlossaryManager(5497): lib_glossary.so can't be loaded
08-31 15:50:55.178: D/dalvikvm(5497): GC freed 699 objects / 54432 bytes in 300ms
08-31 15:50:56.671: D/dalvikvm(5497): GC freed 65 objects / 2600 bytes in 230ms
08-31 15:50:59.374: D/dalvikvm(5497): GC freed 178 objects / 7992 bytes in 36ms
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/dalvikvm-heap(5497): 6432832-byte external allocation too large for this process.
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/(5497): VM won't let us allocate 6432832 bytes
08-31 15:50:59.374: D/AndroidRuntime(5497): Shutting down VM
08-31 15:50:59.374: W/dalvikvm(5497): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e2e0)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:494)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:461)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:366)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at com.image.process.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:121)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1925)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4425)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:850)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
08-31 15:50:59.374: E/AndroidRuntime(5497):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 15:50:59.397: I/dalvikvm(5497): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-31 15:50:59.397: I/dalvikvm(5497): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: post your image processing code.

Comment: what are src.width and src.height of the image? (asking because even 29kb file could has very big dimensions and so, would need a lot of memory).

Comment: the src is the input of the image
I use this to load the image

InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.testingimage);
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

Comment: before passing bitmap to src , try to recycle bitmap

Comment: how to measure the dimensions of the image??

Comment: ImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()
ImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()

Comment: Agrawal
your recycle bitmap means something like bitmap.recycle()??

because I just initial the bitmap when pass to src, so I guess there're not way to recycle, right?? please teach :)

Comment: yes you are initializing for the first time, but if you are using many images using src then its good to recycle before passing src to bitmap.Need to see your code, i dont think just 29kb image can cause memory issue

Comment: I post some of my code above, please check, thank you very much :)

Comment: bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); Instead of this line try this line 
    bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new InputStream(is)); Why you are using static bitmap method, that might be causing the issue

Comment: I got this  
"Cannot instantiate the type InputStream"  
= ="

Comment: I am so stupid... I don't quite get what you mean...
change the code with this bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new InputStream(is)); right???
or what others???
I am I am not smart on this...

Comment: yes , i have posted my answer will  solve your issue

Comment: sorry not solved
by the way I use Android 2.1 as developing environment...

Comment: how you are setting bitmap on image?? please try without static method.That's the issue

Comment: what do you mean by bitmap setting, I just use the code above nothing more...
and removing static method doesn't help...

Comment: just remove your static method and calling method line following my answer , it will help

Comment: tried but problem still exist
is it related to my testing image or some other problem??

Comment: instead of processedImage try testing image. post logcat for errors

Comment: post your 42nd line code from MainActivity

Comment: sorry left a while..
42nd line code is the one you ask me to "Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage , bitmapImage.getWidth(),  bitmapImage.getHeight(), false);"
I changed a to false instead of null as it didn't allow me to use null, and I tried true, but results are the same...

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage , bitmapImage.getWidth(),  bitmapImage.getHeight(), null);

processedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```